# Setup resolvconf to query specific dns server based on domain?

Tags: vpn, dns

I have a VPN through which I like to be able to hit the DNS servers for one domain and I have a local (to my subnet) DNS server I like to hit for another domain. Both are internal DNS servers so records for many of the resources are not available outside the private networks.

When I run a query that successfully hits the DNS server that doesn't have that domain's information it returns "Name or service not known" as one would expect.

Can I setup my computer to know that if Domain A try these dns servers and if Domain B try those dns servers.

Answer (score 1):

This might help: https://serverfault.com/questions/391914/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-specific-dns-for-a-specific-domain

I did the following:

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq.conf
server=/dev/10.4.4.37
log-queries
strict-order
```

This is twofold, one to obey the order the nameservers come in from DNS, since our admins have decided to send both internal and external dns-es

and the other is to force internal .dev lookups to go to a specific internal DNS